# Reconstitute a database from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, cdc, debezium

I'm designing a proof of concept of a system that relies on Kafka and has a database.

Using Debezium (an open source distributed platform for change data capture from database), i will produce events to the kafka cluster when a change occurs.

Having some retention date on the Kafka, i want to imagine a scenario where i have a crash on my database, and i want to recover data from the Kafka cluster..

Which is the best approach to design this kind of recovery system?

I'm thinking about mapping database indexes and Kafka indexes.. when a problem/data loss occurs on a database index, i reconstitute it from the right Kafka index

what do you think guys?

Comment: Take a look at the Confluent JDBC Sink Connector. You can point it to the output produced by Debezium and it can write that data back into a database.

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track, what's the issue you're running into?

Answer (score 1):

I've designed our replication product (IDR from IBM) to answer scenarios like this and the problem space is actually much more tangled than it may originally appear.   I can't give you all our secrets, but maybe some areas your likely going to need to consider, if that's valuable to you.

Likely you will need a notion of transactional consistency.  You'll have to have a way of ensuring that the data you apply from Kafka back to your source database is transactionally consistent across all the tables in your replication set.

That is to say, you want to ensure that if your applying data from transaction 33 that made it into topic 1 (representing table 1), you also need to make sure that you applied the data from transaction 33 that made it into topic 2 (representing table 2).   You also need to ensure you end at a transaction boundary, or else you have a corrupted database as partial transactions are not likely to be acceptable.   Finally you need relative order if there is referential integrity on your source database, which means when applying data from a transaction that wrote to multiple topics, you'll need to figure out which one came before the other if the source tables have RI.   These are some of the fundamental ones, then you start looking at edge cases and how duplicates are dealt with.

I gave a talk about our solution and the theory behind it at the 2018 kafka summit in San Francisco.  If your interested give it a listen.....

https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf18/a-solution-for-leveraging-kafka-to-provide-end-to-end-acid-transactions/